# Can child controls use their parent's datasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have the following mark-up:

```
<div class="section">
    <p runat="server" id="sectionName"></p>
</div>
<div class="label">
    <div class="activity-header">Activity</div>
    <div class="status-header">Status</div>
    <div class="comment-header">Comment</div>
</div>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptActivity" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="under-label">
            <div class="activity">
                <%#Eval("ActivityName")%>
                <input type="hidden" name="activityId" value='<%#Eval("ActivityId")%>' />
            </div>

            <div class="status">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatuses" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div class="comment">
                <textarea name="comments" cols="35" rows="3" name="comment" style="float: left; margin: 0px 0px 0px 25px; font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><%#Eval("Comment")%></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PhumafConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Status]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The datasource for the rptActivity Repeater is List and Helper is defined as below:

```
public class Helper
{
    public string ActivityName { get; set; }
    public long ActivityId { get; set; }
    public long StatusId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I am binding the relevant fields to the properties of the entity and am binding all the ddlStatuses to a datasource which returns all statuses.. However, since this is an update screen I want to have the previously selected status selected, and I have that Id through the prop StatusId of the Helper entity.

Tried setting SelectedValue of ddlStatuses to `<%# Eval("StatusId") %>` but it threw an exception that I can only call props from the datasource to which the control is bound.

Basically I have the StatusIds I need to make them selected in ddlStatuses.

How can I do that?

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that one of the solutions I had in mind is including `List<Status>` as a property in the helper class, that way I'll have the statusId as well as all other statuses, however that won't work if I can't use the parent's datasource.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ItemCreated event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcreated.aspx

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to assist me with this prob. I am not quite sure how this helps? What should I do in the OnItemCreated event of the repeater? What data do I have access to through the EventArgs?

Comment: `(Helper)e.Item.DataItem` will give you the underlying source. Then use `DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FindControl("ddlStatuses")` and select the relevant value here. I didn't test this but should work, let me know if you have problems

Comment: for some odd reason it would not find ddlStatuses. I use DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList) FindControl("ddlStatuses");
Line 50:             ddl.SelectedValue = helper.StatusId.ToString(); and i get null pointer exception on line 50.. It would not find the ddl

Comment: Maybe I should mention that all of this happens within a user control.. I'm trying to access the ddl from the same user control that the drop down list lives in so that shouldnt make any difference I think

Comment: make sure the parent element is the repeater control http://forums.asp.net/t/1495510.aspx/1 Page.FindControl will not find it. I can't write up a full solution, but you should have the bits and pieces you can put yourself together now.

Comment: thank you adam. Still can't confirm that your solutoin works. I sure hope it does! Cheers

Comment: I  make some correction  :) DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlStatuses")